# Écrit-on "Arabie saoudite", "Arabie Saoudite", "Arabie séoudite" ou "Arabie Séoudite" ?

Tags: usage, toponymes, géographie

Quelle graphie faut-il privilégier ?

- Arabie Saoudite
- Arabie saoudite
- Arabie Séoudite
- Arabie séoudite

Answer (score 4):

Selon [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabie_saoudite), c'est :

> Arabie saoudite

ou (en usage auparavant, mais très peu usité actuellement)

> Arabie séoudite

Comment: Toujours selon Wikipédia, *séoudite*, bien que plus usité avant, est désormais plus rare. Il est apparemment plus correct d'utiliser *saoudite*, selon les normes  ISO 233 et DIN 31635.

Comment: @Lyzvaleska: C'est exact, je l'ai rajouté.

Answer (score 1):

En France, les recommandations sont produites par le [Conseil national de l’information géographique](http://cnig.gouv.fr/) (CNIG).

Les noms de pays se trouvent dans [ce document](http://cnig.gouv.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/CNT-CNIG-Pays-et-villes-du-monde_r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9.pdf), et on peut y lire « Arabie saoudite », et comme nom officiel « le Royaume d’Arabie saoudite ».